# Oracle: Select from table (1;2)

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to create a virtual table with a similar syntax

```
SELECT 'sk: ' || #1 || ' ; pdf: ' || #2
FROM TABLE('1, 2', '3, 4')
```

And obtain something like this

```
SELECT 'sk: ' || '1' || ' ; pdf: ' || '2'
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'sk: ' || '3' || ' ; pdf: ' || '4'
FROM DUAL
```

I can create Objects.

I've seen something useful here: [Oracle: split string to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904828/oracle-split-string-to-rows)

But that was an Array and now I need a Matrix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
create type sk_pdf_type is object (sk number, pdf number);

create type sk_pdf_tab_type is table of sk_pdf_type;

select * from table
  ( sk_pdf_tab_type ( sk_pdf_type (1, 2)
                    , sk_pdf_type (3, 4)
                    )
  );
```